# Writing multiple Arrays into an Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Whenever I've been trying to write an array to any type of a list I get the same output and I don't seem to understand where I'm doing wrong. For some reason, every array instance in the Arraylist equals to last cycle of the for loop.

Here's the example code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String[]> al = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] a = new String[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            a[0] = "boo";
            a[1] = String.valueOf(i);
            al.add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

With the output

```
[[boo, 3], [boo, 3], [boo, 3], [boo, 3]]
```

Comment: Here's a nice SO post that might help you to understand the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/3145960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your array into your for loop, otherwise you are just using the same variable

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    String[] a = new String[2];
    a[0] = "boo";
    a[1] = String.valueOf(i);
    al.add(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem.  You need to create the array inside the loop.  Otherwise you are overwriting the same one.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String[]> al = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            String[] a = new String[2];
            a[0] = "boo";
            a[1] = String.valueOf(i);
            al.add(a);
        }
    }
}
```